# By using min_element(v.begin(),v.end()) - v.end(); getting wrong output for a certain vector array 10 10 58 31 63 40 76

Tags: c++, c++17

`n=7`
`10 10 58 31 63 40 76`

For this When I am using `min_element(v.begin(),v.end()) - v.end();` I am getting the index as -7 but I should be getting -6 as it comes first from the end where am I wrong?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Why is -6 the correct answer?

Comment: I want the index of the minimum element and that as you can see is 10 and when I am starting the search from the end (-1)  the first 10 is coming at -6 but I am getting -7 as output.

Comment: The issues is in the fact, that `.begin()` points to 1st item, but `.end()` points to the one after the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`min_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/min_element/) returns the first occurrence:

> An element is the smallest if no other element compares less than it. If more than one element fulfills this condition, the iterator returned points to the first of such elements.

Your range is [v.begin(),v.end()), so the first occurrence would be the first element of `v`. The iterator pointing to the first element is 7 positions away from the end iterator.

If you want to get the last occurrence, you can use reverse iterators instead: `rbegin` and `rend` and then convert the result to a forward iterator.